# Can someone run me through using heaviside cover-up for this decomposition

Tags: partial-fractions

Can someone run me through using Heaviside cover-up for this decomposition:
$$
\frac{2}{(x-2)(x+3)(x+1)^3} 
$$

I have calculated the decomposition traditionally but can't get consistent answers using Heaviside. Any help appreciated :)

edit: I calculated the answers traditionally to be:
$$
\frac{-7}{108(x+1)}+\frac{1}{20(x+3)}+\frac{1}{18(x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{3(x+1)^3}+\frac{2}{135(x-2)}
$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: A knight could probably run you through using a sword, though he might not find Heaviside cover-up sharp enough.